# Why does SQL Server keep variable state even if transaction is rolled back?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have written a script to do a little experiment:

```
use MyDatabase;
declare @variable int;
set @variable = 5;
begin tran test
    set @variable = 6;
rollback tran test;
select @variable;
```

As you can see, `@variable` is `declare`d at the start of the script, initialized with 5 and then inside a `transaction` it is set to 6. After the `transaction` is rolled back, we display `@variable`, which still has a value of 6, despite the fact that its value change was inside a `transaction` which was rolled back since then. I would have expected the selection to yield a result of 5. What is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because transactions are used to maintain the *real* data, the data in tables (not variables, not table variables).  That's about all there is to it.

This is useful for scenarios where you may want to rollback but return some individual value from within the transaction as an indication of why you rolled back (perhaps throwing or just retuning a variable status code).

Answer (score 2):

Consider what it would take for the variable to obey transactional semantics. You would need to write all changes to a transaction log (perhaps not *the* transaction log) where they could be rolled forward and back arbitrarily. And for what? Variables by their nature are ephemeral, so you wouldn't restore them in the case of a database or server crash. So, it's a  high cost, low reward operation. Not the quadrant you want to be in.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.